# One drive syncing deleted local files

Tags: backup, file-transfer, storage, onedrive

Some folders and files were copied from local C:\ to OneDrive.

After (or during) the copying process, I deleted some folders and files from C:\ .

Now OneDrive forever shows a blue circular arrow means it's currently being synced. (but the files and folders are no longer there, so nothing to be synced).

OneDrive still shows these folders and files (deleted from C:\ already). And when I tried to delete these folders and files from OneDrive, it shows warning "this is no longer located in ... Verify the item's location and try again"

[image]

I tried the appraoches [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-could-not-find-this-item-this-is-no-longer-located-in-path-verify-the-items-location-and-try-again/) but not taking effects.

How can I remove them from OneDrive? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to restore the files deleted from C: ?  Assuming so, do that, go to One Drive, delete the files from One Drive and sync back to C: which should then delete the files from C:

Comment: @John, I've ever tried that - but there are many files under different folders, I am not able to replicate all the exact locaitons.

Comment: If you know One Drive to have the files you need, consider breaking the One Drive sync (control panel, sync settings), move the files on C: to another drive (USB drive), restart and set up syncing again.